# Can you help me with configuring Glassfish and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

After much struggle, I managed to first connect a web application with a remote Informix engine through JDBC. There is really nothing documentation about it, or I have not been able to find.

Then, the next natural step was to connect the web application with a remote Informix engine through a connection pool.
Again, it cost me a lot, but a lot of work done with Informix, as examples anywhere with MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle abound, but Informix, nothing. The same can configure the connection pool in Glassfish, and ping settings after a successful connection message me back, and from what I understand, already be set correctly.

Now, I find it impossible to connect to the datasource created in Glassfish through Hibernate. My project uses JSF 2.2 + PrimeFaces + Hibernate.

My connection pool is called "PromoGas" and my datasource called "jdbc / promogas".

My "hibernate.cfg.xml" file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate     Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="hibernate/SessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/hibernate/jdbc/promogas</property>
        <property  name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="pojos/CbtesCoop.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="pojos/CbtesCptos.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="pojos/CptosOtrosSum.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="pojos/Clientes.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This configuration I have armed through different tutorials for MySQL, but adapting it to Informix.

My "web.xml" file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And, my "glassfish-web.xml" is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish  Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java  code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

What surprises me is that the tutorials do not speak the file "web.xml" nor the "glassfish-web.xml". I think some configuration is missing on any of these files or both, but can not find anything on the web about it. Maybe I'm wrong.

When I run the application, the error appears to me is as follows:
"Unable to lookup JNDI name [java: / hibernate / jdbc / promogas]"

For how little I know, i need a context, but in the tutorials do not speak any of that.

I would be grateful to anyone who can guide me on the subject.

A hug!

Gustavo

Comment: The error is clear : ``hibernate.connection.datasource``

Comment: I think the error lays here : ``hibernate.connection.datasource`` its value is ``java:/hibernate /jdbc/promogas`` there is an extra space after hibernate word remove it and try again

Comment: Haven't tried myself but found [this](http://somethingaboutprogramming.blogspot.de/2012/05/eclipse-glassfish.html) on the web; it might help you.